# $AB-BA$ is nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ nilpotent matrices. Show that $AB-BA$ is a nilpotent matrix if and only if $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvector $\alpha$.

I tried if $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvector $\alpha$, then due to $A\alpha=0=B\alpha$ we have $(AB-BA)\alpha=0$. Then I don't know how to continue ... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true.  For example, the nilpotent matrices 
$$ A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & -1\cr 0 & 1 & -1\cr}$$
share an eigenvector $ \pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr 0\cr}$,
but $$AB - BA = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & -2\cr 0 & 0 & -1\cr}$$
is not nilpotent.